# Can SlidingWindows have half second periods in python apache beam?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow, apache-beam

SlidingWindows seems to be rounding my periods. If I set the period to 1.5 and size to 3.5 seconds, it will create 3.5 windows every 1.0 second. It expected to have 3.5 second windows every 1.5 seconds.

Is it possible to have a period that is a fraction of a second?

Comment: could you post your code? which version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/2600/files so should be available in the next beam release. Thanks for catching this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible; I've filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-662 to address this